# Refactor multiple cases from switch

Tags: java

```
TestDTO testDTO = new TestDTO();
    
for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {
    switch (attribute) {
    case "CATEGORY":
        testDTO.setCategory((String) attribute);
        break;
    case "DESCRIPTION":
        testDTO.setDescription((String) attribute);
        break;
    case "NOTE":
        testDTO.setNote((String) attribute);
        break;
    case "FEATURES":
        testDTO.setFeatures((String) attribute);
        break;
    case "INDICATOR":
        testDTO.setIndicator((String) attribute);
        break;
    case "LABEL":
        testDTO.setLabel((String) attribute);
        break;
    case "TYPE":
        testDTO.setType((String) attribute);
        break;
    default:

    }
}
```

As you can see in above code, we are using multiple case for setting data. Code is working fine.

Is there any way for reducing multiple cases for setting those data.

In the above code, the problem is maintainability. Because suppose if we have 30 fields, then we need to put 30 cases for that.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: I don't think so ... if you don't know the order of `row.getAttributes()`.

Comment: I don't fully understand the use case. Your current code selects a setter based on a string and calls the setter with the same string? (e.g. it calls `testDTO.setCategory("CATEGORY")`).

Comment: This feels like a test helper function that is building DTOs from data rows from a spreadsheet or CSV file. And when you say it's working fine, as @isnot2bad has observed it ought to be setting the column value in the DTO, not the column name.

Comment: Why is your element type `Object` rather than `String`? The downcast involves an overhead and is not statically type-safe.

Comment: It gives a compilation error. `Cannot switch on a value of type Object. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted`

Answer (score 5):

Without refactoring you cannot do anything really helping the situation. Also you will need to add specific code for every field anyway - this is obvious

In abstract situation what you could do would be to implement [factory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or [strategy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern and e.g. register proper handlers for every type of attribute - something like

```
Map<Object, BiConsumer<TestoDTO, Object>> handlers; // then you can add for example handlers.put("TYPE", (d, a) -> d.setType(a))
```

And just iterate over attributes

```
row.getAttributes().forEach(a -> handlers.get(attribute).accept(dto, a)); // ofc you need to handle all situation like NPE, no key etc
```

In scope of mapping objects you could use some existing tool like [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) or [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) because it's quite possible that these tools will resolve your issue out of the box

Last and least (:)) solution is to use some reflection, map attribute to field name, extract setter... Don't do this :) it's filthy, insecure, hard to write and understand - will cause many issues you will regret but because it's an option I'm mentioning this

Answer (score 1):

You can use **reflection** to refactor it like below:

```
TestDTO testDTO = new TestDTO();

for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {

    Method method = testDTO.getClass().getMethod("set" + capitalize((String) attribute), String.class);
    method.invoke(testDTO, (String) attribute);
}
```

The capitalize func:

```
public String capitalize(String string) {

    return string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a robust solution you can also build your association using enumerated types and method references, and conveniently encapsulate the map into a single type. Plus, it's pretty obvious how to add new fields:

```
enum DTOMap
{
    CATEGORY(TestDTO::setCategory),
    DESCRIPTION(TestDTO::setDescription); 
    
    private final BiConsumer<TestDTO, String> attributeConsumer;
    
    private DTOMap(BiConsumer<TestDTO, String> attributeConsumer) {
        this.attributeConsumer = attributeConsumer;
    }
    
    public static void execute(TestDTO testDTO, Object attribute) {
        String attributeAsString = (String) attribute;
        DTOMap.valueOf(attributeAsString.toUpperCase()).attributeConsumer.accept(testDTO, attributeAsString);
    }
}
```

With this your switch statement can be reduced to a single line:

```
for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {
    DTOMap.execute(testDTO, attribute);
}
```